# GARCH(1,1) fails to converge in "rugarch" in R

Tags: r, garch

My code is very simpe

```
require(rugarch)
require(quantmod)
    #Daily GARCH(1,1)
    date_from = c("1996-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2004-01-03", "2008-01-04", "2012-01-05")
    date_to = c("2000-01-01", "2004-01-02", "2008-01-03", "2012-01-04", "2016-08-20")
    forex = vector(mode = 'list', length = 5)
    for (i in 1:5) {
      getSymbols("EUR/AUD", src="oanda", from = date_from[i], to = date_to[i])
      forex[[i]] = EURAUD
    }
    EURAUD = Reduce(rbind,forex)
    EURAUD$DEURAUD <- diff(log(EURAUD$EUR.AUD))
    spec7 = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)),
                       mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0), include.mean = TRUE))
    roll_7 = ugarchroll(spec7, EURAUD[,2], forecast.length = 1500, refit.every = 50, windows.size = 1500, refit.window = 'moving', solver = 'hybrid', calculate.VaR = FALSE, keep.coef = FALSE)
```

Unfortunately it fails to converge. What are my alternatives? The standard GARCH(1,1) is crucial as it is proven by Hanen and Lunde (2005) that provides the most accurate forecasts and I nee as a benchmark model for my thesis.

Comment: Hansen and Lunde (2005) do not say that GARCH(1,1) is the best or uniformly better than the rest. They only say that no other model is uniformly better than GARCH(1,1) for the data they study. The second statement is much weaker than the first one. See also Ghalanos ["Does anything NOT beat the GARCH(1,1)?"](http://unstarched.net/2013/01/07/does-anything-not-beat-the-garch11/) for counter-evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a GARCH model is sensible for your data (daily log-returns on currency exchange rates), here are some possible solutions:

- Try different starting values. Most of the times this should do the job.
- Add a negligible amount of noise to the original data (enough to get the solver unstuck but still not affecting the parameter estimates noticeably). Either do this once or perhaps multiple times and average over the outcomes.
- Try a different model: GARCH(1,1) with variance targetting, GARCH(1,1) with a different conditional distribution (e.g. Student-$t$ in place of Normal) -- if this is still a satisfactory benchmark for you.

Comment: I tried with skew-student and normal inverse Gaussian error distributions. I I played with various ARMA specification for the conditional mean but nothing seems to make my model converge. My example is reproducible. Could you please run some of your ideas and get back to me?

Comment: Also the daily GARCH is not the only that I am working with. I just need to further investigate the findings of Hansen and Lunde for the forex rates.

Comment: Ok by utilising your first point I made it work. I changed the date interval `ugarchroll(spec7, EURAUD$DEURAUD["2012-01-01/2015-12-31"], forecast.length = 86, refit.every = 50, windows.size = 1500, refit.window = 'moving', solver = 'hybrid', calculate.VaR = FALSE, keep.coef = FALSE)`