# R ugarchfit: is there a convergence indicator?

Tags: r, time-series, convergence, garch

Say I want to fit GARCH(1,1) models to several time series in a loop. I have tested some simple code like this:

```
library(rugarch)    
spec <- ugarchspec(distribution.model = "std")
fit <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = s)
```

where `s` is one of my time series.

I have noticed that sometimes the GARCH algorithm doesn't converge. Following a good answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231280/garch1-1-fails-to-converge-in-rugarch-in-r), I have realised that often it's sufficient to remove a few points from the series to get convergence.
As I have many time series, I was thinking of implementing a loop where, in case of no convergence, the algorithm tries to run GARCH on the series after it has removed a few points.

However, in order to do that, I need an indicator in the output of `ugarchfit` that would let me automatically detect whether the GARCH algorithm converges or not. Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rugarch/versions/1.3-6/topics/uGARCHfit-class) for the object of class `uGARCHfit` and search the word "convergence"; you will find what you need. Essentially, you just need to apply the method `convergence` to the object, like `convergence(fit)` and see if the value is zero (indicating convergence) or not (indicating nonconvergence).

Comment: @Nonancourt, You are welcome!